# Is it worth developing on ethereum? Will the chain last?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, cryptokitties

After crypto kitties, many people are wondering if the scaling issue will ever be solved. The traffic is exponential, what would happen if 2 more crypto kitties came out at the same time?

I decided to ask the experts (you guys) who know the most.

Comment: Hi there. I've flagged this as off-topic, as it's likely to lead to subjective answers that will almost certainly lead into opinionated, drawn-out discussion. You're also unlikely to get impartial advice: most people here have some investment in Ethereum (be it financial, emotional, or otherwise), so any answers you get are likely to be skewed in a positive direction.

Answer (score 2):

Ethereum is still very young, and has major scalability improvements coming down the pipeline. There are also some operations that shouldn't be done on-chain as they are too resource intensive. CryptoKitties did this with their gene science code from what I was able to read on medium about decompiled  genescience bytecode, which would've partially alleviated the strain on the network but not entirely.

It is also my personal belief that the CryptoKitties architecture leaves much to be desired in the fact that they simply crammed everything onto the blockchain, as opposed to deciding which pieces should be on-chain, and which pieces should be off-chain. Etherdelta is a very good example of this. It's entirely put on the chain, and suffers from horrible transaction delays and performance issues. I would reckon the CryptoKitties code could be drastically redesigned to prevent the issue it caused.

Comment: So from what im reading, all it takes is one person to write bad contract code and the entire network suffers. Doesn't seem like something that can easily be fixed.

Comment: Not necessarily, you have to bear in mind the current total computing capacity of the ethereum network  at this point in time which in all honesty is quite low compared to what it can be with the coming scalability upgrades. In this particular case you have bad contract code, that was being used by thousands of people to the point that you're consuming 13% of network traffic, it's quite easy for poor coding to backlog the network.

Comment: Once again i dont know anything about all this, but from those who do know a little. ive heard that the ethereum devs are way behind and have no real working code for scaling.

Comment: I'd like to see some sources defending those statements. I know the devs are hard at work with Sharding and Proof of Stake.

Comment: have no sources, this is just word of mouth and not any kind of information to be taken seriously. but if they are working like you say they are, when do you think it will be implemented? thanks for the info though appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum has one of the most talented Dev Teams in the crypto space who will always work on improving this chain. Also Ethereum is about to implement Proof of Stake which will change a lot as well.

Comment: thanks for answer, sounds like a lot of opinions and speculation though. no hard facts.

Comment: You're right but right now the entire crypto space is just speculation. But in my opinion the dev team ist the biggest selling point of the chain